# Using class to write xml in specific format

Tags: c#, xml

I am try to understand how to write an xml by passing variables to a class. Here is my class:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public partial class Output {

    private OutputReportType[] itemsField;


    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ReportType", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public OutputReportType[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }
}


public partial class OutputReportType {

    private OutputReportTypeReportsReport[][] reportsField;

    private string nameField;


    public OutputReportTypeReportsReport[][] Reports {
        get {
            return this.reportsField;
        }
        set {
            this.reportsField = value;
        }
    }

        get {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }
}


public partial class OutputReportTypeReportsReport {

    private OutputReportTypeReportsReportItemsItem[][] itemsField;

    private string nameField;


    public OutputReportTypeReportsReportItemsItem[][] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }


    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name {
        get {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand how to achieve the format:

```
<output>
   <OutputReportType> 
       <OutputReportTypeReportsReport>
           <OutputReportTypeReportsReportItem>
          </OutputReportTypeReportsReportItem>
      </OutputReportTypeReportsReport>
  </OutputReportType>
</output>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Output output = new Output()
            {
                outputReportType = new List<OutputReportType>() {
                     new OutputReportType() {
                          outputReportTypeReportsReportItemsItem = new List<OutputReportTypeReportsReportItemsItem>() {
                              new OutputReportTypeReportsReportItemsItem() {
                                   name = "Abc"
                              }
                          }
                     }
                 }
            };

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Output));

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, output);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();

        }
    }

    [XmlRoot("output")]
    public class Output
    {
        [XmlElement("OutputReportType")]
        public List<OutputReportType> outputReportType { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("OutputReportType")]
    public class OutputReportType 
    {
        [XmlElement("outputReportTypeReportsReportItemsItem")]
        public List<OutputReportTypeReportsReportItemsItem> outputReportTypeReportsReportItemsItem { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("OutputReportTypeReportsReportItemsItem")]
    public class OutputReportTypeReportsReportItemsItem 
    {
        [XmlElement("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

}




​
```

Comment: It uses `<outputReportTypeReportsReportItemsItem>` instead of `<OutputReportTypeReportsReport>` and `<name>` instead of `<OutputReportTypeReportsReportItem>`. Like I said, it was close. It just needs a few things renamed but the process was correct. You wrote your code against the (incorrect) code the OP wrote, not the schema the OP was trying to achieve which he lists at the end of the question.